# Irrationality of $\cos 2\pi / n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, trigonometry, galois-theory

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Is $\cos (2\pi/n)$ irrational if $n$ is not $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$ or $6$?

Comment: See [Niven's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niven%27s_theorem)

Comment: $n=3$ gives $-1/2$.

Comment: And of course n=-1,-2,-3,-4,-6, assuming n integer (which you didn’t say).

Comment: Sounds like the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [proof using Galois theory posted on Wilson Ong's Blog](https://wilsonong.wordpress.com/2010/06/25/when-is-cos2pin-irrational/).

We know $\cos(2\pi)=1$ and $\cos(\pi)=-1$. Let $n \geq 3 $ be a positive integer and $\zeta = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}$ be the first root of unity. Assume $\cos(\frac{2\pi}{n})=\frac{\zeta + \zeta^{-1}}{2}$ is a rational number. Consider the Galois group [$Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)/\mathbb{Q}) \cong (\mathbb{Z} / n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity#Galois_group_of_the_primitive_nth_roots_of_unity). If $\cos(\frac{2\pi}{n})$ is rational, any $\sigma \in Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)/\mathbb{Q})$ must fix it. Since $\zeta$ is a root of the polynomial $t^n -1 \in \mathbb{Q}[t]$, so is  $\sigma(\zeta)$. Thus  $\sigma =\zeta^{j}$ for some $1 \leq j < n$. Apply this: $$\cos(\frac{2\pi}{n})=\sigma \left( \cos(\frac{2\pi}{n}) \right)=\sigma \left(\frac{\zeta+\zeta^{-1}}{2} \right)=\frac{\zeta^{j} + \zeta^{-j}}{2}=\cos(\frac{2\pi 
 j}{n})$$
It follows that $j \in \{ 1, n-1 \}$. Hence $\sigma \in Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)/\mathbb{Q}) $ sends $\zeta$ into $\{ \zeta, \zeta^{-1} \}$, which shows $\big| Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)/\mathbb{Q}) \big| = \big| (\mathbb{Z} / n\mathbb{Z})^{\times} \big| \leq 2$. Thus the value of [$ \big| (\mathbb{Z} / n\mathbb{Z})^{\times} \big| = \phi(n)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n#Structure) is $1$ or $2$. Since [the totient function $\phi(n)$ is multiplicative and $\phi(p^k)=p^{k-1}(p-1)$ for prime $p$ and $k \geq 1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Computing_Euler's_totient_function), we can conclude that

1. any prime $p \geq 5 $ does not divide $n$
2. $2^k \mid n$ implies $k \leq 2 $
3. $3^k \mid n$ implies $k = 1 $

Thus $n = 3, 4, 6$.

Conversely, we have \begin{align*} &\cos(2\pi)=1 \\ 
&  \cos(2\pi/2) = -1 \\
&  \cos(2\pi/3) = -\frac{1}{2}   \\
&  \cos(2\pi/4) = 0 \\
& \cos(2\pi/6)= \frac{1}{2}
 \end{align*}

Therefore, for positive integer $n$, $\cos (\frac{2\pi}{n})$ is rational if and only if $n=1,2,3,4,6$.